# Why does this string creation macro work?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I have a utility macro "STR" in some old C++ code that I used to create formatted strings for printing.

```
#define STR(__msg) ({ std::stringstream __ss; __ss << __msg; __ss.str(); })

cout << STR("Hello" << "World" << "!" << "\n");
```

I couldn't remember why this code works.  I did some googling and didn't find anything useful so I figured I'd ask here.  Any takers?

Comment: It doesn't work all the times (e.g., `STR((true)? 1 : 0);`).

Comment: `({` `})` macro's syntax is a g++ extension. It "returns" last's instruction's value, so whole macro makes a `std::stringstream __ss`, transfers `__msg` to it, and "returns" stringizyed `__ss`'s value, and that's what you print.

Comment: I'd recommend you to avoid this syntax, it makes simple things complicated and compiler-dependent.

Comment: "statement expression" is what I needed to google for.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html  This code will only ever be used on Linux/gcc, so being compiler dependent isn't a problem.